# Cypress mock module federation micro frontent

Tags: cypress, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

My application has an auth micro frontend which creates a singleton instance for sharing the auth state with all the micro frontends in the application.

The auth class exposes some methods like so

```
{
    getUser: () => {...} 
    isAuthenticated: () => true
    ...
}
```

In the app I load in the MF, get the instance, and call the methods I need.

```
import { Auth } from 'auth/services/Auth';

const auth = Auth.getInstance();

const component = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated();
    ...
}
```

I use webpack module federation to load in the MF at run time.

```
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'mf',
            remotes: {
                auth: 'auth@https://localhost:3099/remoteEntry.js',
                ...
            },
        }),
    ],
```

Is there a way I can mock the auth instance in Cypress? I would like to call the methods the auth instance exposes with mock data.

Comment: Could you intercept the auth requests and provide mock responses so then you wouldn't need to mock the specific methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of mocking the internals of an app is to expose a reference for the test to modify.

```js
import { Auth } from 'auth/services/Auth';

const auth = Auth.getInstance();

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.auth
}

const component = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated();
    ...
}
```

**test**

```js
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win.auth, 'isAuthenticated').returns(true)
  },
})
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Will try it out and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Not to advertise some tool, but for this I would use Mockoon to record and mock the authentication part.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't need to mock an api response for the auth rather the actual JS module.